# How to call or use a .js file using onclick Reactjs functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have .js file called Edit which is used for edit purpose. I have another .js file called Add. I have a dialog box in edit.js which will open when I click a button. But I don't want to use a button instead I want to get that a dialog box when I click anywhere on box. I tried using onclick in div tag but I didn't get any response.
[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RfNL.png)
so if you observe we got a edit button there if click it I am getting form/dialog box for editing the content. but I want that form or dialog box to open when I click anywhere on the yellow box.

```
<div id='color' className='div2' key={item.id} style={{width: 340,
# border: '5px solid white',textIndent:-30,paddingRight:32,paddingLeft:40,whiteSpace:'pre',paddingTop:15, backgroundColor:item.currentColor}} onClick={()=>{editpage(item.id)}} >
```

this is what I used  for calling function for getting form in another .js file. It is part of a mapping function.` there is a onclick event I used that whenever I click on the box or content which is all under div tag I need to go to that function and there go to edit and then form but it didn't work

the function to which it goes is this:

`const editpage=(id)=>{ <Edit id={id}></Edit> }`

I want to send a id as a parameter which is passed to Edit.js.
I used `<Edit/>` because it is a another js file which I am importing in Add.js file.

I am not able to get the output can you please me with this.
how I can use this when I click on color box should open a form which is indeed in another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is successfully calling a function on the click event:

```
onClick={()=>{editpage(item.id)}}
```

But what does that function do?  Absolutely nothing:

```
const editpage=(id)=>{ <Edit id={id}></Edit> }
```

The function doesn't return anything (not that returning from a click handler does anything either of course), doesn't perform any operations, nothing.  It's just a single JSX expression.

Take a different approach entirely.  Add your component to the markup, but wrap it in a condition based on state.  For example, consider this state value:

```
const [openEditPage, setOpenEditPage] = useState();
```

The purpose of this state value is to keep track of which `item.id` should currently have its "edit" component visible.  (Default to `undefined` so none are visible by default.)

Use this value when rendering the components:

```
<div id='color' className='div2' key={item.id} style={/*...*/} onClick={()=>{editpage(item.id)}}>
  {openEditPage === item.id ? <Edit id={item.id}></Edit> : null}
</div>
```

So in this case the `<Edit>` component will only be rendered if `openEditPage === item.id`.  Which is what the `editpage()` function can do:

```
const editpage = id => setOpenEditPage(id);
```

Clicking on the `<div>` would invoke the `editpage` function, which updates the state value, which triggers a re-render, and in the new render the `<Edit>` component is shown because the condition would be `true`.